# Why do all my auto-generated thumbnails with GD in PHP have black backgrounds?

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

Well I am using the following code to take any old image into a 160x120 thumbnail, the problem is if there is overflow the background is always black.  I've been snooping around the PHP docs but none of these functions seem to have any kind of color parameters.  Any ideas or pointers would be great!

```
$original = 'original_image.jpg';
$thumbnail = 'output_thumbnail.jpg';

list($width,$height) = getimagesize($original);
$width_ratio = 160 / $width;
if ($height * $width_ratio <= 120)
{
    $adjusted_width = 160;
    $adjusted_height = $height * $width_ratio;
}
else
{
    $height_ratio = 120 / $height;
    $adjusted_width = $width * $height_ratio;
    $adjusted_height = 120;
}
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(160,120);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);
imagecopyresampled($image_p,$image,ceil((160 - $adjusted_width) / 2),ceil((120 - $adjusted_height) / 2),0,0,ceil($adjusted_width),ceil($adjusted_height),$width,$height);
imagejpeg($image_p,$thumbnail,100);
```

Also if you're unclear what I mean, take [this image](http://www.andrew-g-johnson.com/thumb.jpg) and consider that it was originally just red text on a white background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [imagecreatetruecolor function](http://www.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) creates a black canvas.

Use the imagefill function to paint it white...

Answer (score 1):

Add this before you copy the original into the new:

```
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
ImageFillToBorder($image_p, 0, 0, $white, $white);
```

EDIT:

Actually, I didn't know about imagefill . . .

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);
```

Comment: +1 for good post, but llama beat you to the punch for accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

dont use imagecreatetruecolor instead imagecreate, I think that would solve